# Get a list of TIDs from a PID in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, pid

Sometimes I want to condition on the existence of a TID (thread identifier) so that I can see when it finishes. For example, suppose I make a large file copy in nautilus. And then I realize it's going to take 3 hours (suppose I realize too late and I don't want to cancel and do it form the CL). I would like to tell my computer to shutdown after Nautilus finishes the copy. If there is big I/O (as of course there will be in a file copy), I can use iotop and that nicely gives me the TID. How can I condition on that TID finishing? Also, suppose a thread isn't doing a lot of I/O. How can I get it's TID? I know how to get PIDs (e.g. `ps` or `cat /proc/<PID>/status`) and when there's only one thread the TID is the same as the PID, but what if there is more than one thread?

Here is what I do to condition on a PID:

```
while ps aux | grep [2]9228 > /dev/null; do sleep 20s; done; echo "Process Finished"
```

Comment: You are talking about `/proc` - would the `linux` tag be more appropriate than the `unix` tag?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma you are right. I thought that proc existed on Unix also. It's not POSIX?

Comment: @XuWang: By way of example: OSX (Darwin) is considered POSIX-compliant (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)), but does NOT have `/proc`.

Comment: @XuWang - I don't think it is a Posix thing, though I don't have a citation for that.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs has a list of common OSes that have /proc - several unix flavours, but as mklement0 notes, OSX is not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume this question is [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) specific and not [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) in general.

`/proc/<PID>/task/` contains a list of directories, one for each thread in the given process.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the TID with `ps`.

Script-friendly command (only TIDs, one per line, no header line):

```
ps -L --pid <PID> -o tid=
```

or, for more verbosity:

```
ps -L --pid <PID> -O tid
```